# Get followers of a twitter account and then the followers of that one API tweepy

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I need to retrieve the followers of an account of twitter and then the followers of the first followers, but now I'm only getting the first ones after I type the account name.

```
screen_name=input('Type the screen name: \n')
for follower in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name).items(30): 
    print(follower.screen_name)
```

How can I after this retrieve the followers of the given 30

Comment: It looks like you already know how to retrieve a list of followers given a screen name. You just need to repeat this process for all the screen names returned by your initial query.

Answer (score 0):

This is adapted from my code, so I didn't test this but works in my code. Also, I very quickly ran into rate limits, which I don't account for here.

```
def get_follower_list(num_followers, id):
    follower_list = []
    for follower in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, id).items(num_followers):
        follower_list.append(follower.screen_name)
    return follower_list

# get initial list of followers
num_followers = 5
user_list = ['GEODIS_Group']
for user_handle in user_list:
# print(user_handle)
    followers = get_follower_list(num_followers, user_handle)
print(followers)

new_followers_list =  followers

#iterate through new list
num_followers = 5
user_list = new_followers_list
for user_handle in user_list:
# print(user_handle)
    followers = get_follower_list(num_followers, user_handle)
print(followers)
```